# Vuetify - How can I use the Data-Table search feature to filter by a dynamically calculated field value?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Trying to use Vuetify's Data-Table to search/filter based on the computed value of a field. As feel free to jump into the codepen and type in some values for yourself. For example, I have it setup in such a way that the email address field can be searched by; however, the name of the employee and phone record fields are not functional.

Codepen 
https://codepen.io/Jasilo/pen/PooLjbE

VUE:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card>
      <header>How can I search by the computed Name and Phone fields?</header>
   <v-card-title>
     <header>Employee List</header>
     <v-spacer></v-spacer>
     <v-text-field v-model="search" append-icon="search" label="Search" single-line hide-details></v-text-field>
   </v-card-title>
   <v-data-table v-bind:headers="headers" v-bind:items="employeesArray" v-bind:search="search">

     <template v-slot:item.email="{ item }">
       <div> 
         {{ item["email"] }} </div>
     </template>
     <template v-slot:item.name="{ item }">
       <div> 
         {{ getName(item) }}
       </div>
     </template>
     <template v-slot:item.phone="{ item }">
       <div> {{ getPhone(item) }}</div>
     </template>

     <template v-slot:no-data>
       <div icon="warning">
         {{ gridEmpty }}
       </div>
     </template>
   </v-data-table>
  </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card>
      <header>How can I search by the computed Name and Phone fields?</header>
   <v-card-title>
     <header>Employee List</header>
     <v-spacer></v-spacer>
     <v-text-field v-model="search" append-icon="search" label="Search" single-line hide-details></v-text-field>
   </v-card-title>
   <v-data-table v-bind:headers="headers" v-bind:items="employeesArray" v-bind:search="search">
     <template v-slot:item.email="{ item }">
       <div> 
         {{ item["email"] }} </div>
     </template>
     <template v-slot:item.name="{ item }">
       <div> 
         {{ getName(item) }}
       </div>
     </template>
     <template v-slot:item.phone="{ item }">
       <div> {{ getPhone(item) }}</div>
     </template>

     <template v-slot:no-data>
       <div icon="warning">
         {{ gridEmpty }}
       </div>
     </template>
   </v-data-table>
  </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you have to use the custom-filter

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thanks for posting a good Q and providing a Codepen to make it easier for others to help you. I've posted a working solution to your problem. If it solves your Q then please mark it as accepted so others know that your Q has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to use a computed property:

```
  computed: {
    employeeTableData() {
      return this.employeesArray.map(e => {
        return {
          email: e.email,
          name: this.getName(e),
          phone: this.getPhone(e),
        };
      });
    },
  },
```

Then change `v-data-table` to use `employeeTableData` instead and directly reference the attributes.

[Working codepen](https://codepen.io/xieliming/pen/mddoBmJ)

You can then search `XD` or `666-` and it will correctly filter on name and phone number.